# How to retrieve an attribute value from a jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve the 'id' from the following jquery object 'temp':

```
<div class="combo-box-list open">
          <select name="filter" style="margin-bottom: 0px; display: none;" class="combo-original-element" data-original-id="filter">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">Status</option>
                <option value="2">Type</option>
                <option value="3">Start Date Range</option>
            </select>
</div>
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and what is `object 'temp'` is it a variable?

Comment: thought about; `$.ajax()`?

Comment: `$(temp).find("select").attr("data-original-id")`

Answer (score 1):

use **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```
 $(".open select").attr("data-original-id")
```

or use **[data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

```
 console.log($(".open select").data("original-id"))
```

Comment: It's stored in a variable - "temp". How should it be accessed in that case?

Comment: it is object ? how did you stored that  , what is the value it has or show the temp

Comment: "temp" has the div in it which I have pasted above in the question.

Comment: @ambar `$(temp).find("select").attr("data-original-id")`

Comment: @Satpal, thanks! It works. Is there any other way to achieve the same? Just asking.

Comment: @ambar, `$(temp).find("select.combo-original-element").data("original-id")` What else you need

Comment: @Satpal, I meant is it possible to retrieve it without using 'find' ?

Comment: @ambar, Yes but that will be long

Comment: Avoid using more specific selectors like `select.combo-original-element` unless you actually need them. As there's is only 1 select element with that class, you don't need the type prefix, so something like `$('.combo-original-element').data('original-id')` also will work.